# Pick images from specific directory

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-bitmap

I'm getting Bitmaps using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_BACKGROUND);
```

How can I open Media Picker to get Bitmaps from specific directory?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourFolder/yourImg.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this not what I meant. I've edited the question.